# Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating support Toolbar

Tags: android-xml, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I keep getting this error when running my app on Android 5.0 emulator. App crashes on launch with this error log. On JellyBean (my phone 4.2.2) however it seems to run fine no issues.

Using Android Studio version 1.0.0, latest support libraries, gradle 1.0.0 (as per the build.gradle file)

```
12-10 17:18:29.354    3245-3245/com.suleiman.wifibuddy.d E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.suleiman.wifibuddy.d, PID: 3245
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.suleiman.wifibuddy.d/com.suleiman.wifibuddy.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.suleiman.wifibuddy.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:176)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.suleiman.wifibuddy.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:176)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0e0073
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:756)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:319)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:133)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawable(TintTypedArray.java:62)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:249)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:892)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:802)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.suleiman.wifibuddy.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:176)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Hope someone could help me out with this :/

Comment: How did you set your theme on the Toolbar?

Comment: I followed this to set the theme  https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon closer inspection at the **Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0e0073** pointed to the drawer toggle. Fixed the issue by completely removing the ActionBarDrawerToggle (support v7). 
Weirdly it crashes on lollipop when the drawer is set to be overlapped by the status bar (as per the Material Design guidelines)

Comment: Off-topic: I saw [this edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16061938) where you update a link to your blog. However, both the old and the new link result in a page saying "Error establishing a database connection". You may want to fix that.

Comment: Link works. Tested. You may want to refresh your cache and try.

Comment: It works now.  BTW, I myself prefer sites where I get to see the content first. Asking people to sign up, before showing them anything...personally I consider that bad user experience.